# Unique not working in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unique

This is my code

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names | orderBy:'-name' | unique: 'name'">
    {{ ' Name =  ' + (x.name | uppercase) + ' &nbsp; &nbsp; Roll No = ' + x.rollno }}
  </li>
</ul>
<script>
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        {name:'aaaaaa',rollno:'1'},
        {name:'aabbbb',rollno:'2'},
        {name:'aabbcc',rollno:'3'},
        {name:'ddeegg',rollno:'4'},
        {name:'ddeegg',rollno:'4'},
    ];
});
</script>
```

**It displays results as something like this**

- Name = DDEEGG | Roll No = 4
- Name = DDEEGG | Roll No = 4
- Name = AABBCC | Roll No = 3
- Name = AABBBB | Roll No = 2
- Name = AAAAAA | Roll No = 1

**But I want results with no duplicate entry like**

- Name = DDEEGG | Roll No = 4
- Name = AABBCC | Roll No = 3
- Name = AABBBB | Roll No = 2
- Name = AAAAAA | Roll No = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include angular.ui.filter.js then include `ui.filters` module in your app

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.filters']);
```

Then use

```
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in names | orderBy:'-name' | unique: 'name'">
      {{ ' Name = ' + (x.name | uppercase) + ' &nbsp; &nbsp; Roll No = ' + x.rollno }}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/q3WiFzI2Wwy2NlW0t78V?p=preview) Here

Comment: I include this but not working. <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/dist/ui-utils.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>, can you tell me library url ?

Comment: @MuhammadRiaz you can only include unique filter from here https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui-OLDREPO/blob/master/modules/filters/unique/unique.js