# Displaying unique values of JSON array in Dropdown list box using angularJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, json

My JSON Array named employee:

```
[{"id":15,"userId":"Vikram.Swaminathan@gmail.com","fromDate":"2016-01-05","toDate":"2016-01-14","typeofLeave":"Sick Leave","region":"IND","status":"Accepted","daysapplied":8}
{"id":16,"userId":"Vikram.Swaminathan@gmail.com","fromDate":"2016-01-13","toDate":"2016-01-13","typeofLeave":"Paternity Leave","region":"IND","status":"Accepted","daysapplied":1}
```

In my Html:

```
<select>
<option> ng-repeat="email in employee"  {{email.userId}} </option>
</select>
```

My Dropdown should display only one time basically how many times i applied leaves it should display Vikram.Swaminathan@gmail.com in dropdown only once

```
<select>
<option ng-repeat="email in employee | unique:'userId' ">{{email.userId}}</option>
</select>
```

I don't know how to use unique in angularJS how to include ? When i include i get error as `Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider`

Comment: @Pankaj : I dont know how to include unique like this:

<select>    
<option ng-repeat="email in employee | unique:'userId' ">{{email.userId}}</option>
</select>

Comment: You first need to add `angular-ui-bootstrap` reference in your app. and then include that module inside your app module.. get more information about implementation from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29620135/2435473)

Comment: @Vikram your JSON has some issues , fix it first

Comment: @PankajParkar I was including the wrong JS file i took correct file from the answer you suggested. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Sajeetharan There wasn't any mistakes bro in JSON. Missed ] which was a typo but thank you

Comment: @Vikram Glad to help you..Thanks :)